# React Js : How can i use index number to disable button ( if index = 4 then disable button )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7JHq.png)
i have to create a component where one person can add upto 4 addresses for doing this i have used slice(0,4) in map function but i have to make button disabled when 4 addresses are entered

How can i do this i need a solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of5YR.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: Don't use indices. Your buttons are "things", they exist for a reason, so update your state based on user input, and then just make sure to render a new virtual dom with whatever the tree needs to look like (with `key` attributes, of course, so that React can do all the "which bits to keep, which bits to throw away, which bits to modify-in-place"). You are responsible for saying what things should look like, and React is responsible for updating the UI accordingly. Don't try to do React's job in your own code =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(locations.length < 4) { <button type="button"> Add </button> }` 
So basically the button will appear or dissapear based on if the condition is true or false.

Comment: thank you for this but what if button is outside of map function is it possible to export index number out of map function??

Comment: Are you filling an array of addresses?

Comment: i am quite confused is there any way we could connect verbally i really need help

Comment: I cannot right now but if you give some more details on how do you want your component to work maybe i can help you. So first question is if you want to submit all four addresses at once or 1 at a time?

Comment: let me tell scenario 

i have to create a page where person can add 4 addresses and after adding fourth address the input and buttons should be hidden when user deletes one address from four of the added one then input and button reappears

Comment: please guide me to best practice for doing this

Comment: So you can basically use the length of the array of addresses as condition instead of index. That way you can check how many addresses are already saved.

Comment: wait i am adding UI images it would be more clear

Comment: You can go through the UI and Code images then you can understand what i am trying to do

Comment: So you just need to wrap your inputs and the buttons you want to hide in an if statement where you check the "locations.length < 4" so if it is less than 4 they will appear but if it is equal or more than 4 they will dissapear.

Comment: yeah it is, but the thing is button and input lies outside the map function

Comment: The map function is used only to display all of the addresses in the array. You do not need it for the if statement. The length of the array should dinamically change when you add or delete address.

Comment: so i can show hide buttons via location(array) length is it correct??

Comment: irrespective of map function

Comment: Yes, just try it out with a simple if statement and comment if it worked.

Comment: ohh my god how fool i am, Thank you so much Marin i was just doing it from 13 Hours 

it worked !!! Thank You So Much.

Comment: You are welcome! I will appreciate it if you upvote my comment. Good luck at what you are doing!

Comment: I wish i could but my reputation is not enough to do this please can you drop your email so we could be in touch

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for something like this in your return statement:

```
        <Button
          className="btn-info btn-sm"
          type="button"
          onClick={(e) => clicked(e)}
          disabled={locations.length >= 4}
        >
          Add Address
        </Button>
```

I think you want to use map.size() for the number of addresses in your disable conditional instead of index.

Note that I have been using [Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/) components so the button is a drop-in widget.  If your not using a UI widget library then you should consider it to make things easier.

Comment: i have attached what i have to do is
all i have to do within map function 


 {locations.slice(0, 4).map((location, index) => (

use that index value to toggle buttons state 

such that if index=== 4 then button disabled if less than 4 button enabled

Comment: or how can i export index number from map function

Comment: i am quite confused is there any way we could connect verbally i really need help

Comment: I have been editing my answer several times.   Please look at it again and explain what part your confused about.     I don't think you want to use the index of the last location,  locations size is a much easier to access out side of the map function.   Is the location variable an array?

Comment: yeah its an array

Comment: then you can simply use locations.length to get the number of items in the array.